# Why is this balloon following me?

Tags: electrostatics, fluid-dynamics, buoyancy

There is a mylar (shiny) helium birthday balloon tied to a chair about 2' (60 cm) away from me. It has some freedom to move around because it gradually lost helium & sank a little which reduced tension on its string.

**It is repeatedly coming over and touching me.** If I push it away, after a few minutes it comes back. (I do find this endearing). What could explain this 'phenomenon'?

Sometimes it seems to float away on its own, but more often it lingers right up against me.

I am sitting in a still room whose air is a little bit cool (early morning). There is no perceptible air movement in the room. No ventilation or fans are running. I do have this laptop computer in front of me; it and I are both producing some heat of course.

Could this be thermal air currents? Electrostatic? Perception bias?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possibilities.

1. This is electrostatic. A laptop computer is emitting microwaves having approx 2 GHz wavelength. You can verify this with a 30 years old computer and an FM radio. The microwaves charges the mylar balloon. You are in a room with your feet on the carpet (approx electrically grounded). because of this the balloon is attracted to you. When it touches you, the electric charge goes to ground through you.
2. This is thermal air current. It is early morning. You heat the air around you (approx 20 cm). The heated air goes up, and the static pressure between you and the balloon decreases.